# Facebook PHP SDK 4 in a Silex Framework website?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, silex

I want to integrate **Facebook** functionality into my **Silex** website.
To be more precise the ability to sign in with Facebook.
Once the user is signed in I want to also be able to make API calls to Facebook to post or attend events on behalf of the logged in user.

Using Composer I've added the **Facebook SDK** into my project but now I'm kind of lost on how to proceed with coding the login (**auth**) part and how to make **Facebook Graph API** calls and display the returned data.

I've started with the **Silex Kitchen Edition** (https://github.com/lyrixx/Silex-Kitchen-Edition) as the base for my project, since I'm new to Silex development!

Are there any **tutorials** available? (I can't seem to find any!)
Would be really helpful if someone could help me out or point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this [extension](https://github.com/tobiassjosten/FacebookServiceProvider). It will help you for learning purposes.

Comment: Thanks @Darko for the reply, I've looked into it.. The ServiceProvider was made for the old facebook php sdk version 3.2 :(